# Proper way of providing dependency to spring @Bean in @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In @Configuration class it is possible to create spring bean by using method with @Bean annotation

```
@Component
public class Foo {
}

public class Bar {
  private Foo foo;

  public Bar(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

@Configuration
public class BarConfig {
  @Bean
  public Bar bar(Foo foo) {
    return new Bar(foo);
  }
}
```

But injecting Foo to BarConfig class and using it that way can let you create Bar as well:

```
@Component
public class Foo {
}

public class Bar {
  private Foo foo;

  public Bar(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

@Configuration
public class BarConfig {
  @Autowired
  private Foo foo;

  @Bean
  public Bar bar() {
    return new Bar(foo); // bar() without args
  }
}
```

Is there any difference, from spring perspective, between them? Is 2nd incorrect? What would it break or what would not work because of it?

I managed to find that with 2nd there is no visible dependency to foo from Bar but would it affect anything? Refreshing/reloading spring context would pick up the change in foo while remaking bar, wouldn't it?

Comment: Although at runtime the *might* behave the same they don't necessarily do. There is a change that in your 2nd configuration the `Foo` bean is instantiated very early in the process of starting the application context. Which can lead to an non proxy being injected. Which could mean that things like `@Transactional` or `@Async` (or anything else AOP related) stops working for that bean.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between this two types of autowiring is amount of code that has to be written.

I recommend you to use the first option simply because it is shorter.

The second option is suitable in case if you have to specify `@Qualifier` annotation in pair with `@Autowired` and the been which you want to inject declared in separate configuration.

Comment: Yeah, in both cases you will get BarConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$<HEX>, and Spring will do injection magic. I would also go with the shortest version.

Comment: You can also specify `@Qualifier` on the method argument one no need to create field injection for it.

Comment: Yes, of course. But the way with separate field will be highlighting the dependency.